# Swift how to put array into variable. RevenueCat offerings

Tags: swift

I have the following code from RevenueCat and I would like to put all of my offerings in a variable

The following is not working for me

```
func allOffering(){
  let myOfferings = Purchases.shared.getOfferings { (offerings, error) in
        if let offerings = offerings {
          // Display current offering with offerings.current
          
          
      }
    }

  // print to log
  print(myOfferings)
}
```

I can print all of the offerings this way however I want to put it in a value so that I can use the data in other places in the function

```
func allOffering(){
  let myOfferings = Purchases.shared.getOfferings { (offerings, error) in
        if let offerings = offerings {
          // Display current offering with offerings.current
          print(offerings.current)
          
      }
    }

  // print to log
  print(myOfferings)
}
```

Comment: I doubt that `getOfferings` returns something.

Comment: I edited the questions. I can print to console offerings.current however I am only able to use the values in the if block. I would like to have access to the values outside the if block. I need. access to the data within the function

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25203556/returning-data-from-async-call-in-swift-function, `getOfferings` seems to receive the data asynchronously.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason it's not working is because `myOfferings` is being set to the closure itself, not the actual values it loads. The offerings won't be available outside of the scope of the completion closure yet because they still need to be fetched.

The point of the completion block is that you can execute code once you know for a fact that the offerings are available (or once you've received an error, to which you can then respond appropriately).

The easiest thing to do is to perform any action you need `myOfferings` for inside that completion block - or pass the values as a parameter to other functions:

```
Purchases.shared.getOfferings { [weak self] (offerings, error) in
    if let offerings = offerings {
      self?.doSomething(with: offerings)
  }
}

func doSomething(with offers: [Offer]) {
    // do something
}
```

That might already address what you need. If not, there are other options.

An approach I like to take when I need access to values like this independently from the completion block is to use a LoadingState wrapper, which I can then use to see if the values are available yet. For example:

```
enum OfferingsLoadingState {
    case initialized
    case loaded([Offering])
    case error(Error)
}
```

Then I can make a variable like this:

```
var myOfferings: OfferingLoadingState = .initialized
```

And set its value to the fetched offerings once it's done:

```
Purchases.shared.getOfferings { [weak self] (offerings, error) in
    if let offerings = offerings {
      self?.myOfferings = .loaded(offerings)
  }
}
```

When using `myOfferings` outside of the completion block, you can then check if it's loaded and if it is get the values from it.

```
switch myOfferings {
    case .loaded(let offerings):
        print(offerings)
    default:
        // TODO: do something here if needed
        break
```